# QSqlTableModel: unable to find table when calling submitAll method

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, qt

I want to insert data into an SQLite database using `QSqlDatabase` and `QSqlTableModel`.

The database is being created in an `SqlDatabaseController` class:

**SqlDatabaseController.h**

```
// ...
class SqlDatabaseController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    // ...

private:
    QSqlDatabase _database;
    SqlContactModel* _contactModel { nullptr };

    // ...
```

**SqlDatabaseController.cpp**

```cpp
SqlDatabaseController::SqlDatabaseController(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    // create database driver
    _database = QSqlDatabase::database();

    _contactModel = new SqlContactModel(this, _database);
}

// ...
void SqlDatabaseController::connectToDatabase(const QString &name, const QString &pwd)
    if (!_database.isValid()) {
        _database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

        if (!_database.isValid()) {
            qFatal("[SQL] SqlDatabaseController: Cannot add database: %s", qPrintable(_database.lastError().text()));
        }
    }

    const QDir writeDir { QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation).append("/").append(name) };

    if (!writeDir.exists() && !writeDir.mkpath(".")) {
        qFatal("[SQL] SqlDatabaseController: Failed to create writable directory at %s", qPrintable(writeDir.absolutePath()));
    }

    // Ensure that we have a writable location on all devices.
    const QString fileName { writeDir.absolutePath() + "/db.sqlite3" };

    // When using the SQLite driver, open() will create the SQLite database if it doesn't exist.
    _database.setDatabaseName(fileName);

    if (!_database.open()) {
        qFatal("[SQL] SqlDatabaseController: Cannot open database: %s", qPrintable(_database.lastError().text()));
        QFile::remove(fileName);

        return;
    }

    emit databaseConnected();
}
```

For model data storing, I'm subclassing `QSqlTableModel`:

**SqlContactModel.cpp**

```cpp
SqlContactModel::SqlContactModel(QObject* parent, QSqlDatabase db) :
    QSqlTableModel(parent, db),
    _tableName("Contacts")
{
}
```

As you can see, I'm passing the database to the TableModel so it's able to use this database for all queries.

Afterwards, I'm creating the tables:

**SqlContactModel.cpp**

```cpp
void SqlContactModel::create()
{
    createTable();

    setTable(_tableName);
    setSort(2, Qt::DescendingOrder);
    // Ensures that the model is sorted correctly after submitting a new row.
    setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
}

// ...

void SqlContactModel::createTable()
{
    qDebug() << "[SQL] Creating table" << _tableName << "for database" << QSqlDatabase::database().databaseName() << ".";

    if (QSqlDatabase::database().tables().contains(_tableName)) {
        qDebug() << "[SQL] Database table" << _tableName << "already exists. Exiting createTable().";

        emit contactTableCreated();
        return;
    }

    QSqlQuery query { "SOME_QUERY" };

    if (!query.exec()) {
        qFatal("[SQL] SqlContactModel: Failed to create table: %s", qPrintable(query.lastError().text()));
        return;
    }

    if (!submitAll()) {
        qFatal("[SQL] SqlContactModel: Failed to submit createTable query: %s", qPrintable(lastError().text()));
    }

    emit contactTableCreated();

    qDebug() << "Done creating table" << _tableName << ".";
}
```

Now, I want to insert something into my table like this:

**SqlContactModel.cpp**

```cpp
// ...

void SqlContactModel::addContact(const QString& contactName, const QString& id, const QByteArray& avatar)
{
    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO '" +
                  _tableName +
                  "'(id, name" +
                  (avatar.isEmpty() ? "" : ", avatar") +
                  ") VALUES (:Id, :Name" + (avatar.isEmpty() ? "" : ", :Avatar") +
                  ")");

    query.bindValue(":Id", id);
    query.bindValue(":Name", contactName);

    if (!avatar.isEmpty()) {
        query.bindValue(":Avatar", avatar);
    }

    if (!query.exec()) {
        qFatal("[SQL] SqlContactModel: Unable to execute query in addContact: %s", qPrintable(query.lastError().text()));
        return;
    }

    for (auto const& table : QSqlDatabase::database().tables()) {
        qDebug() << "Table: " << table;
    }

    if (!submitAll()) { // <-- here's where it breaks
        qFatal("[SQL] SqlContactModel: Failed to submit addContact query: %s", qPrintable(lastError().text()));
        return;
    }

    qDebug() << "[SQL] Added contact " << contactName << "(" << id << ") to table " << _tableName << ".";

    // emit contactListChanged();
}
```

The query executes just fine and the data is being stored in the database, however since I'm using `setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);` on my model, I would need to call `submitAll()` on my model to be updated properly. When calling `submitAll()`, however, I keep getting an error:

`[SQL] SqlContactModel: Failed to submit addContact query: Unable to find table Contacts`.
As you can see in the code above, I iterated through all tables of the database and I get the following output:

```
Table:  "Contacts"
Table:  "Conversations"
```

which is why I'm quite sure the table *does* exist.

Is this some kind of encoding error or **why is `submitAll()` not able to find my table `Contacts` in the database?** What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you `setTable(_tableName.toStdString().c_str());` instead of `setTable(_tableName);`? Does your controller live in different thread?

Comment: No sorry, I changed it, it was a test to check if it's a string conversion problem.